# Changing page count in FragmentStatePagerAdapter's getCount() based on preferences

Tags: android

After reading up hordes of SO answers, this challenge remains.

This is the relevant piece of code in a v4 `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        int count = 2;
        if (pref_dealsOnly)
            count = 1;
        return count;
    }
```

Like you already guessed, it just crashes with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 2, found: 1 Pager id: com.droid.shopper:id/shopperMainPager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.sndroid.globeshopper.shopper.ShopperJournal$JournalPagerAdapter
```

I fail to understand why the exception occurs. 
Please help on how to accomplish what seems to be so simple and apparent - **to return a `getCount()` value in a v4 `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` dynamically**. Kindly let me know if more code is required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getCount()` may be called several times by the `ViewPager`. It must remain constant, for the life of that `PagerAdapter`, for reliable results with `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

In theory, you could do what the error message tells you and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `PagerAdapter` at the point when `getCount()` will start returning a different value. While that can work with a custom `PagerAdapter` implementation, neither `FragmentPagerAdapter` nor `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` used to handle it all that well. I wound up creating [another `PagerAdapter` implementation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager) to support adding and removing pages. It is possible that `FragmentPagerAdapter` and/or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` are behaving better nowadays, though I doubt it.

In your case, it may be a matter of swapping in a different `PagerAdapter` at the point when `pref_dealsOnly` changes value.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but its me - still do not know what to do next. 

Do you mean `getCount()` should look like this?:

`if (pref_dealsOnly)
  myAdapter = new DifferentAdapterForDealsOnly()` ?

Pray, even plainer English please! Code will be even more appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: @NarayanaJ: Never change your page count. Replace your `PagerAdapter` in the `ViewPager` when the preference changes.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant solution - made my day, after so many days of struggle!
Thanks a ton, @CommonsWare!